# Angular Material Autocomplete incorrectly shows all options after one is selected and the field re-focused

Tags: angular, angular-material

Example in Stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctyf9w

1 - Click on the field

2 - Select an option (don't type to filter)

3 - Focus out of the field

4 - Focus back the field

All options are showed like the filter was not working and if you force filtering and re-select the value, the problem stops.

Stackblitz was updated to correct the 'bug' found.

If anyone finds a better implementation of a Material Autocomplete that is able to enforce object selection, please share.

Comment: I don't understand the issue, I don't know what the two fields you have in stackblitz example are supposed to do

Comment: @IvanS95 Try following the list of actions I mentioned in my question. When you type something in the autocomplete, it will show the available options... why does it show ALL available options when one is selected and the field is re-focused?

Comment: I did follow you instructions, but the field works fine, I start typing to filter one option, leave focus, refocus, and shows only the option matching the filter

Comment: @IvanS95 1 - type and filter, 2 - select an option, 3 - lose focus, 4 - re-focus.

Comment: Exactly what I did, but now I see the issue is only happening when you select the second option, doesn't happen when you select the first

Comment: The first time it happens only if you select the 2nd option, after doing that once, it keeps happening for all of them

Comment: @IvanS95 Sorry, try this: 1 - click on the field and type nothing, 2 - select one of the options, 3 - lose focus, 4 - re-focus

Comment: Yeah, also happens in that case, I'm looking at the code right now and the docs to see if there something about that behavior... Consider adding this info to the main question so people now in which particular scenario the issue happens

Comment: @IvanS95 The valueChange is not getting fired when you select an option and the filter never knows it should have updated the filteredOptions, so all the options stay inside the variable.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the filteredOptions not being an Observable

Comment: @IvanS95 adding an 'else { this.filteredProductList = []; }' to the 'if (typeof value === 'string')' in the valueChanges solved the issue. This autocomplete component feels very immature and full of problems when trying to enforce selection. Thanks for your help. If you want you can write the answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: I'm sure there might be more efficient ways to handle the component, I think is pretty useful but might be hard to work with for particular scenarios... You were able to solve the issue so you should add an answer yourself so others can see it :)